# Facing issue in using multiple isolates from main thread

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-isolates

I'm spawning an isolate (first isolate) from main thread to make network calls to the backend to get a large amount of data and process them into local DB.

During this process when I spawn another isolate (second isolate) from same main thread to carry out another task. When the second isolate sends data to main thread through the SendPort once the task is completed it stops the  tasks carried out by the first isolate. Any help please?

Is it something to do with receive port since both the isolates are spawned from main thread and both will have a port to the main thread to share memory, does closing any of the port causes other ports also to be closed?

Comment: *"does closing any of the port causes other ports also to be closed?"* - no

Comment: @pskink any reasons on why the other isolate stops?

Comment: @pskink unable to view the page

Answer (score 1):

You can work with multiple isolates pointing to the same Main ReceivePort, but each isolate will need to have its own ReceivePort. For example:

Isolate 1 ReceivePort -> Main ReceivePort <- Isolate 2 Receive Port

But you should be careful about how you will receive and save the isolates ports on the Main Thread. Since they need to be send using the Main ReceivePort.

I recommend you to check out the plugin easy_isolate, it provides a simple way to work with multiple isolates with well-explained documentation.

https://pub.dev/packages/easy_isolate

Comment: Im having separate receive port for each isolates

Comment: _isolate = await Isolate.spawn(checkOutBoxAndSendToServer, map);
    _receivePort.listen((message) {
      log("MESSAGE FROM ISOLATE : ${message.toString()}");
      if(message.toString()=="stopOutbox"){
        _receivePort.close();
      }

    },onDone: (){
      log("DONE");
      this.stop();
    });

Comment: void stop(){   _isolate!.kill();
      _isolate = null;}

Comment: i'm sending a message as stopOutbox from isolate once the task is completed and on the main thread on receiving it i'm closing the receive port

Comment: _isolate = await Isolate.spawn(checkAndDownloadMessages, map);

Comment: Similarly another isolate which already runs in the background has its own receive port but yet it gets stopped

Comment: I created an example using your cases, please check out and give me a feedback

https://gist.github.com/lubritto/71782e03986ceb767e4309e4fa574405